# How to add an arrayList to this child class?

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance, arraylist

Context - So there are two classes that uses inheritance. The EmployeeService is the parent class and the EmployeeInfo is the child class.

What do I need help with - So I am trying to insert an arrayList to the parent class that combines the information of the **experience** and **position** and makes a new arrayList called serviceList.

And when I call a super() in the child class, I should be able to call the arrayList rather than the String variables  (experience, position).

**To put it short, I should basically be able to pass an arrayList as the third parameter in the child class employeeInfo method instead of String experience or String position**

Parent class -

```
public class EmployeeService () {
    private String experience;
    private String position;
    
    public EmployeeService (String experience, String position) {
        this.setExperience (experience);
        this.setPosition(position);
    }
    
    public String getExperience() {
        return experience;
    }

    public void setExperience(String experience) {
        this.experience = experience;
    }
    
    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "Experience - " + experience + "Position" + " - " + position;
    }
    
}
```

Child class -

```
public class EmployeeInfo () {
    private String firstName;
    private String address;
    
    public EmployeeInfo (String firstName, String address,String experience, String position) {
        super(experience, position);
        this.setFirstName (firstName);
        this.setAddress(address);
    }
    
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "Name - " + firstName + "Address" + " - " + address + super.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what your intent is. Your main class does not even compile as is and your description is hard to follow. Do you want to add a `List` or a `Map` to the parent class?

Comment: I want a list for the parent class.

Comment: I did put the main class with errors so it'd be a little easier to understand with the comments.

Comment: But what is `employeeList` in your main class? It seems to be a `List<EmployeeService>` so do you want a `List<EmployeeService>` property in your `List<EmployeeService>`?

Comment: It's a hashMap that's used to create a new object with the child class, not the parent. And it's part of an assignment, I'm sorry if the instructions are vague. All I need help with is to be able to pass an arrayList from the parent class to the child class.

Comment: It makes no sense at all. Is it an `ArrayList` or a `HashMap`?

Comment: An arrayList. I'll remove the main class if that helps. Ignore the HashMap please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the property and an additional constructor to the parent class as follows:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EmployeeService {
    private String experience;
    private String position;
    private List<String> serviceList;

    public EmployeeService (String experience, String position) {
        this.setExperience (experience);
        this.setPosition(position);
    }

    public EmployeeService (String experience, String position, List<String> serviceList) {
        this(experience, position);
        this.serviceList = new ArrayList<>(serviceList);
    }

    public String getExperience() {
        return experience;
    }

    public void setExperience(String experience) {
        this.experience = experience;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Experience - " + experience + "Position" + " - " + position;
    }
}
```

Then adapt your child class:

```java
import java.util.List;

public class EmployeeInfo extends EmployeeService {
    private String firstName;
    private String address;

    public EmployeeInfo (String firstName, String address, String experience, String position) {
        super(experience, position);
        this.setFirstName (firstName);
        this.setAddress(address);
    }

    public EmployeeInfo (String firstName, String address, String experience, String position, List<String> serviceList) {
        super(experience, position, serviceList);
        this.setFirstName (firstName);
        this.setAddress(address);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Name - " + firstName + "Address" + " - " + address + super.toString();
    }
}
```